# Intermediate blob storage before uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, design-patterns, data-processing

I am designing a service that receives large amounts of binary data (proprietary images). I want to accumulate these multiple images into a single S3 object and finally upload to S3. It doesnt make sense to store the accumulation in memory as I want to be able to horizontally scale the service by running multiple instances. As S3 is "replace-only" I cant keep uploading the object to S3. In such a case, what is the best option to store this intermediate data before uploading to S3? One option I am thinking is to use redis but it has limits on the size of value not to exceed to 512 MB.

Comment: What about EFS?

Comment: Agreed, EFS is a good idea. If your code is running on Amazon EC2 and multiple instances need access to the same data, then EFS acts much like a traditional network filesystem. However, you might have problems with multiple instances wanting to update the same file simultaneously.

Comment: Put the parts in S3 before stitching them together.  I agree that EFS doesn't solve the problem of coordination; if you use filesystem level locking you won't have scalability.

Comment: Thanks all.. I will explore the using S3 to stich it together.